# Can I delete my pepk file after uploading it to Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-keystore, android-app-signing

To my understanding, a `.pepk` file is only used by Google Play to sign my app on their end.
After sending them the `.pepk` file, I generate my own Java Keystore which contains a key to sign subsequent releases of my app. The `.jks` file is also used to generate a certificate for the upload key (`.pem`) which is also uploaded to Google Play. This leads me to believe that I only need to keep the `.jks` and `.pem` files, and not the `.pepk` file correct?